# How to map the 'Menu key' to 'AltGr key'?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, remapping

I'm on a Dell Mini 910 with English keyboard and Ubuntu 11.10 also in English, and I want to keep it this way. But most of my typing is in Spanish so I need the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key to get Spanish characters without switching my keyboard layout.

How can I map the <kbd>Menu Key</kbd> to <kbd>AltGr</kbd>?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is to be done in X.

It can be done with 'xmodmap'.

```
xmodmap -e "keysym Menu = ISO_Level3_Shift"
```

Put the following in the the file '.Xmodmap' in your home directory to make it load automatically when logging in.

```
keysym Menu = ISO_Level3_Shift
```

Comment: You point me into the right direction. This what works for me:clear    mod3
keysym Menu = Mode_switch
add     mod3   = Mode_switch